# How to trace a dotted (not dashed) path in Mapbox-gl-js?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I'm using the latest version of Mapbox-gl-js and I would like to trace a path in the form of equidistant circles, like Google Maps does when we ask a "walking" route:

[image]

With Mapbox-gl-js, I've tried the dashed and circle layouts but they don't answer my needs:

```js
// Dash
map.addLayer({
  id: 'my-points',
  type: 'line',
  source: 'my-data',
  paint: {
    'line-color': 'gray',
    'line-width': 10,
    'line-dasharray': [1, 1],
  },
});

// Circles
map.addLayer({
  id: 'my-lines',
  type: 'circle',
  source: 'my-data',
  paint: {
    'circle-color': 'red',
    'circle-radius': 3,
  },
});
```

The dashed style respects the equidistance but doesn't show circles:

[image]

The circles style shows circles but only at the provided coordinates, not all the long of the route.

[image]

So my question is: is there a way to have equidistant dots, or circles, or customizable patterns traced along a geojson/lineString path?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use a `symbol` layer, with some kind of circle icon as a symbol, it should be closer to what you want. Something like:

```
{
   type: 'symbol',
   source: 'route',
   layout: {
     'icon-image': 'mycircle',
     'symbol-placement': 'line',
     'symbol-spacing': 50,
   }
```

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#layers-symbol

I suspect you will have to simplify your route a lot to make it render nicely though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to be what I want, however I'm stuck at the symbol creation. The documentation says it requires a png spritesheet + a json sprite definition file, but I don't understand where to put them exactly... is there a "symbol layer tutorial" available somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: found it: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image/
and it works. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 8):

While still not quite perfect, you can get closer to what you want with the `line` layer style using the the `line-cap` layout prop and setting your line segment length to zero:

```
    layout: {
      'line-cap': 'round'
    },
    paint: {
      'line-width': 10,
      'line-dasharray': [0, 2]
    }
```

[image]